# Streams use for map computation from list with counter

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream, iteration

I have the following for loop which I would like to replace by a simple Java 8 stream statement:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>("a", "b", "c");
Map<String, Long> wordToNumber = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Long index = 1L;

for (String word : words) {
  wordToNumber.put(word, index++);
}
```

I basically want a sorted map (by insertion order) of each word to its number (which is incremented at each for loop by 1), but done simpler, if possible with Java 8 streams.

Comment: what if there is another `a`? like `a, b, c, a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work (though it's not clear why `Long` is needed because the size of `List` is `int`)

```java
Map<String, Long> map = IntStream.range(0, words.size())
    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(words::get, Long::valueOf));
```

The code above works if there's no duplicate in the `words` list.

If duplicate words are possible, a merge function needs to be provided to select which index should be stored in the map (first or last)

```java
Map<String, Long> map = IntStream.range(0, words.size())
    .boxed().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(words::get, Long::valueOf, 
        (w1, w2) -> w2, // keep the index of the last word as in the initial code
        LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
    ));
```

---

Similarly, the map can be built by streaming `words` and using external variable to increment the index (`AtomicLong` and `getAndIncrement()` may be used instead of `long[]`):

```java
long[] index = {1L};
Map<String, Long> map = words.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> index[0]++, 
        (w1, w2) -> w2, // keep the index of the last word
        LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   Map<String, Long> wordToNumber = 
   IntStream.range(0, words.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    words::get,
                    x -> Long.valueOf(x) + 1,
                    (left, right) -> { throw new RuntimeException();},
                    LinkedHashMap::new
            ));
```

You can replace that `(left, right) -> { throw new RuntimeException();}` depending on how you want to *merge* two elements.

Comment: First time I see this choice to raise a RTE in `mergeFunction`. Very interesting. I think this will be more efficient if you used a range starting at 1 to avoid unboxing just to do + 1: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, words.size())` then `Collectors.toMap(words::get, Integer::longValue,...`

Comment: @ernest_k agreed. I will leave to the OP to apply this refactoring...

Comment: Hmm... on second thought, I have a bug there... would have to be `x -> words.get(x - 1)`, making the unboxing necessary still. Maybe this can use a mutable reduction: `IntStream.range(1, words.size() + 1).collect(() -> new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>(), (map, i) -> map.put(words.get(i-1), (long) i), Map::putAll)`

Comment: @ernest_k I do not know why, but I have never been a fan of `collect` from `IntStream`, it's just a bit harder to read for me. Still, that is a viable option too, excellent point.

Comment: `x -> Long.valueOf(x) + 1` will unbox the `Integer`, convert it to `long`, box it `Long`, unbox it to `long`, add one, box the result to `Long` again. You surely want to use `x -> x + 1L` instead…

Answer (score 1):

> I basically want a sorted map (by insertion order) of each word to its
> number (which is incremented at each for loop by 1), **but done simpler**,
> if possible with Java 8 streams.

You can do it concisely using the following `Stream`:

```
AtomicLong index = new AtomicLong(1);
words.stream().forEach(word -> wordToNumber.put(word, index.getAndIncrement()));
```

Personally, I think that either

```
Map<String, Long> wordToNumber = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
    wordToNumber.put(words.get(i), (long) (i + 1));
}
```

or

```
Map<String, Long> wordToNumber = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (String word : words) {
    wordToNumber.put(word, index++);
}
```

is simpler enough.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different solution. The `Integer::max` is the merge function which gets called if the same word appears twice. In this case it picks the last position since that effectively what the code sample in the question does.

```
@Test
public void testWordPosition() {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "b");
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
    Map<String, Integer> map = words.stream()
            .map(w -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(w, index.incrementAndGet()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Integer::max));
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Output:

```
{a=1, b=4, c=3}
```

Edit:

Incorporating Alex's suggestions in the comments, it becomes:

```
@Test
public void testWordPosition() {
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "b");
    AtomicLong index = new AtomicLong();
    Map<String, Long> map = words.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w, w -> index.incrementAndGet(), Long::max));
    System.out.println(map);
}
```